# Anime.js anime.stagger is not a function

Tags: javascript, anime.js

I'm trying to use the `anime.stagger` function from Anime.js, but I'm getting an error:

> anime.stagger is not a funcion

I'm using the 3.2.0 version.

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.emo');
anime({
    targets: elements,
    bottom: 600,
    easing:'linear',
    left: function() { return anime.random(250,550); },
    duration: 2000,
    delay: anime.stagger(500),
    loop: true,
});
```

Any idea why it's happening and how to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: Most likely, you haven't included `anime` on your page.  Your syntax is correct and if the library is loaded it should work. You'll need to do something like `<script src="anime.min.js"></script>` or `const anime = require('animejs');`

Comment: lool you are right . I did included but at the beginning i was using and old version of anime and i didn't update the source . thanks